# Spring-boot не видит ресурсы из jar но видит если запустить из IDE

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources

У меня есть  spring-boot  проект. В нем мне нужны шрифты. Я использую библиотеку которой нужно передать ссылку на шрифт и она с ним работает. Проблема в том что если шрифт лежит например на диске  `C:\foo.ttF` то она принимает эту ссылку как параметр и подгружает шрифт. Но я не хочу хранить шрифт на диске а хочу в ресурсах проекта, поэтому добавил его в  `resources/static/font/foo.ttf` а подгружаю так

```
public static final String FONT = "classpath:static/fonts/Tahoma.TTF";

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

private Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(FONT);
normalStyle.setFontName(resource.getURI().toString());
```

Все работает если я запускаю из IDE(IntellijIDE)

Но когда я собираю jar и запускаю его то вижу ошибку

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [static/fonts/Tahoma.TTF] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)
        at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource.getURI(AbstractResource.java:99)
        at kg.nurtelecom.services.impl.DefaultPdfService.generate(DefaultPdfService.java:83)
        at kg.nurtelecom.services.impl.DefaultPdfService.createPdf(DefaultPdfService.java:63)
        at kg.nurtelecom.controllers.MainController.generate(MainController.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Программа не видит ресурсы, и я не знаю как это решить.

кусок POM.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

вот распаковал  jar ку

```
SNAPSHOT\BOOT-INF\classes\static\fonts\Tahoma.ttf
```

Comment: значит, они не добавляются в jar

Comment: клевый ответ. спасибо! КЭП.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять на другой путь(убрать `static` из пути). + в собранном JAR есть ваш ресурс? Т.е. он добавлен? Если нет - покажите `POM` файл, раздел `build`

Comment: Попробуйте явно настроить какие директории включать в jar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018394/having-maven2-copy-resources-to-the-build-directory-but-not-bundle-them-in-the

Answer (score -1):

Вам не кажется, что проблема в регистре расширения файла?

`classpath:static/fonts/Tahoma.TTF`

`SNAPSHOT\BOOT-INF\classes\static\fonts\Tahoma.ttf`

Comment: в данном случае регистр не влияет. исправьте, если ошибаюсь